# Aggregate distinct values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb db with 18625 collections. It has following keys:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aab14d2fc08b46adb79d99c"), 
    "game_id" : NumberInt(4), 
    "score_phrase" : "Great", 
    "title" : "NHL 13", 
    "url" : "/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181", 
    "platform" : "PlayStation 3", 
    "score" : 8.5, 
    "genre" : "Sports", 
    "editors_choice" : "N", 
    "release_year" : NumberInt(2012), 
    "release_month" : NumberInt(9), 
    "release_day" : NumberInt(11)
```

Now, i wish to create another dimension/ collection with only genres.

If i use the following query :

```
db.ign.aggregate([ {$project: {"genre":1}}, { $out: "dimen_genre" } ]);
```

It generates 18625 collections, even though there are only 113 distinct
genres.

How to apply distinct here and get the collection for genres with only the distinct 113 values.
I googled, bt it showed that aggregate and distinct don't work together in mongo. 
I also tried : db.dimen_genre.distinct('genre').length
this showed that in dimension_genre, there are 113 distinct genres.

Precisely, 
how to make a collection from existing one with only distinct values.

I am really new to NoSQLs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to group unique values in one document and then [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get back multiple docs:

```
db.ign.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            genre: { $addToSet: "$genre" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$genre"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    { $out: "dimen_genre" }
]);
```

Comment: thanks!! it works, how to make a new collection using this, so that i don't need to call this query again and again

Comment: @NidhiGarg using $out as in your example

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me understand the logic behind so many other queries as well.

Comment: can you explain how to add more than one key to the new collection, eg- taking genre and release_year both ?

Comment: @NidhiGarg `$addToSet` can take an object as an argument: `{ $addToSet: { genre: "$genre", release_year: "$release_year"} }`

Comment: db.ign.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,

$addToSet: { release_year: "$release_year",release_month: "$release_month",release_day: "$release_day" }

        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$release_year"
    },
    {
    $unwind: "$release_month"
    },
    {
    $unwind: "$release_day"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0, release_year: 1,release_month: 2, release_day: 3
        }
    },
    { $out: "dimen_time_practice1" }
]);

I tried the above query, it showed aggregation error..

Comment: @NidhiGarg you must specify field name before `$addToSet` like `{ $group: { _id: null, fieldName: {$addToSet: { release_year: "$release_year",release_month: "$release_month",release_day: "$release_day" } } } }`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
db.names.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$genre", books: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
   ]
)
```

I have tried with Test and Sports as genre

It gives you output something like this

```
{
    "_id" : "Test",
    "books" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aaea6150cc1403ee9a02e0c"),
            "game_id" : 4,
            "score_phrase" : "Great",
            "title" : "NHL 13",
            "url" : "/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181",
            "platform" : "PlayStation 3",
            "score" : 8.5,
            "genre" : "Test",
            "editors_choice" : "N",
            "release_year" : 2012,
            "release_month" : 9,
            "release_day" : 11
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Sports",
    "books" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aaea3be0cc1403ee9a02d97"),
            "game_id" : 4,
            "score_phrase" : "Great",
            "title" : "NHL 13",
            "url" : "/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181",
            "platform" : "PlayStation 3",
            "score" : 8.5,
            "genre" : "Sports",
            "editors_choice" : "N",
            "release_year" : 2012,
            "release_month" : 9,
            "release_day" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aaea3c80cc1403ee9a02d9b"),
            "game_id" : 4,
            "score_phrase" : "Great",
            "title" : "NHL 13",
            "url" : "/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181",
            "platform" : "PlayStation 3",
            "score" : 8.5,
            "genre" : "Sports",
            "editors_choice" : "N",
            "release_year" : 2012,
            "release_month" : 9,
            "release_day" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5aaea3cf0cc1403ee9a02d9f"),
            "game_id" : 4,
            "score_phrase" : "Great",
            "title" : "NHL 13",
            "url" : "/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181",
            "platform" : "PlayStation 3",
            "score" : 8.5,
            "genre" : "Sports",
            "editors_choice" : "N",
            "release_year" : 2012,
            "release_month" : 9,
            "release_day" : 11
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time and solution, but i think i wasn't exactly looking for this at this time :)