# Is there a way to filter a mongo database by the number of occurrences of specific value?

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query

For example if I have a database like

```
Number OtherStuff
1      stuff
2      stuffalso
1      morestuff
1      otherstuff
2      stuff2
3      stuff3
4      stuff4
```

is there a way to get back just those entries matching 'Number' < 4 and there are more than 2 instances? So in this case just those with 'Number' == 1 since there are 3 of them.

Something like `db.find({Number: {$lt: 4}, somethingelsehere})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to check if `Number` is less than `4` and then run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to check how many instances each group has. You can also run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get back original shape of your data:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $match: { Number: { $lt: 4 } } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Number",
            documents: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { count: { $gt: 2 } }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$documents"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$documents" }
    }
])
```

Comment: I'm doing this in jupyter with python and it's saying `NameError: name 'count' is not defined`

Comment: oh, that's a neat thing, thanks! I guess I'll mess with it and see why it's not working.

Comment: hmmm... do you know how to get just the distinct values from the Number column after filtering? Cuz that's what I was really trying to do. But apparently this filtering returns a `CommandCursor` object that's not searchable, so i can't think of an easier way to find distinct values than converting it into a pandas dataframe :\

Comment: @Raksha try to add $group with $addToSet in the next stage, just like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350757/aggregate-distinct-values-in-mongodb/49350848#49350848

Comment: i think i'm doing it wrong cuz it still returns CommandCursor %\ I was hoping for like a list of unique values